# How do I make a ColdFusion Web Service return SOAP instead of WDDX?

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, xml-serialization, wddx

I've created a ColdFusion Web Service, but it's returning WDDX instead of SOAP. How do I make it return SOAP instead of WDDX?

Comment: Perhaps I need to convert my complex data types to xml?

Comment: Depends on what you wanna return.  If XML is good enough, use XML since it's easier then setting up multiple CFCs just to get the SOAP types right.  If you have control on both producer and consumer side, use JSON (super easy, but might have unexpected type conversion on number / integer / date).

Comment: I am only the service provider - I have no control over the consumer side.

Comment: Is there no way for ColdFusion Web Services with Complex Types to return normal XML?

Comment: You may want to update the question to 'How do I make a ColdFusion Web Service return xml'?

Answer (score 1):

For complex objects, you need to setup the CFCs correctly.  Read: [Using ColdFusion components to define data types for web services](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7dbf.html)

**update:** Or, you can create the XML representation of your object yourself with `<cfxml>`, then return the XML object with `returnType="xml"` in `cffunction`.

You may check out coldbox's [XMLConverter](http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/Plugins%3aXMLConverter.cfm) Plugin as code sample for converting built-in CF   complex types into XML.

Comment: That throws an exception, because my returntype is complex.

Comment: Edited my answer based on your clarification.

Comment: Edited my answer based on your clarification, again.

Comment: Ok. But how can I get the method to return properly formatted XML while the WSDL shows the complex type as the return type?

Comment: I'm not a WSDL expert, but as far as I know once you've constructed your XML object, and return it with `returnType="xml"` in your remote `cffunction`, it should work.

Comment: Or do you mean just returning XML? then in that case you want to consume your webservice as non-soap, plain old http web service and call your method using `http://server/foo.cfc?method=bar&arg1=1&arg2=2`

Comment: i'm basically trying to re-create my Web Service from a WSDL that I was provided by the consumer of what they're expecting back. I was hoping there was a way to do this that wasn't so manual, but oh well.

Comment: in that case, maybe you can try `<cfcomponent wsdlfile="" style="document">` and use `returntype="xml"` on the defined method. Good luck

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4784/discussion-between-henry-and-eric-belair)

Comment: +1 for some good ideas and lots of help pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Have the `<cffunction>` return an XML object, and have the "returnformat" parameter be set to "plain".

```
<cffunction name="GetData" returntype="xml" returnformat="plain">
```

Comment: No. I have created a Web Service, and when I call a method, it returns the data I expect, but in WDDX, not in SOAP-formatted XML.

Comment: Edited my answer based on your clarification.

Comment: But now I have to rewrite my complex types as xml.

Answer (score 1):

A CFC method with access=remote ought to return soap, rather than WDDX. I'm sure I've used this functionality for years. What I'm suspecting may be happening is that the content-type is based on the request a client makes. I would download [Soap-UI](http://www.soapui.org/) and test http://your.server/yourCFC.cfc?wsdl to see whether SOAP-UI gets WDDX thrown back at it. If is does, I'm at a bit of a loss, but do report it here anyway and I'll take a further look. 
If Soap-UI sees a proper response, take a look at the headers it's sending and compare them to the request you're making (possibly through the browser?)

You can also use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to record soap-ui traffic and compare that against any other source of requests.

The http request thing above may be completely off, but it's relatively easy to check and I think it's ringing a bell.

You may also want to check the return type of the function you're writing. In order for CF to generate a good WSDL, it needs to be able to extract metadata from the CFC you're returning.

Comment: Yes, SOAPUI showed me that my WebService was working correctly. I was trying to call it directly in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the game but were you hitting it as a plain HTTP request and not as with a SOAP packet?

For example were you doing this:

http://api.example.com/something.cfc?method=test&arg1=val1

instead of an actual SOAP request with envelope, headers, body, etc?

The HTTP request returns WDDX by default or JSON by specifying the returnformat, while a SOAP request will return data in the format you are seeking.